# Save image from PictureBox to specific folder when photo is uploaded to picbox

Tags: vb.net

> System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'

I Get This Error on this line

```
safecopy.Save(path + "\MainPic\" + fullname + ".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

Heres my Code:

```
Private Sub btnUploadPhoto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUploadPhoto.Click
    Dim getlastname As String = tboxLastName.Text
    Dim getfirstname As String = tboxFirstName.Text
    Dim getmidname As String = tboxMiddleName.Text
    Dim fullname As String = getlastname + getfirstname + getmidname
    Dim pcusername As String = GetUserName()
    Dim path As String = "C:\Users\" + pcusername + "\Documents\RMS\Photos" + fullname
    If ofdUploadPhotoMain.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        PicBoxMain.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        PicBoxMain.ImageLocation = ofdUploadPhotoMain.FileName 'Display in PictureBox
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
        End If
        Dim safecopy As Bitmap
        Dim mainpic As New Bitmap(ofdUploadPhotoMain.FileName)
        safecopy = mainpic
        mainpic.Dispose()
        safecopy.Save(path + "\MainPic\" + fullname + ".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        safecopy.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

i want to save the picture to specific folder with specific file name without openning the savefile dialog.

Send Help!

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult  to read and understand, and SHOUTING won't get you an answer any faster. It's also rather rude to come here and shout at us when you're asking for free help to solve *your* problem. Disable your CAPS LOCK here. Thanks.

Comment: okay thanks. noted. didn't mean to be rude, just a habit of making the Title in all caps.

Comment: If you browse through the question titles on the main page, you won't see any posts in ALL CAPS. It's considered to be shouting here just as it is on every other site on the internet.

Comment: How familiar are you with how reference types work in .NET?  When you do this --- `safecopy = mainpic` --- you aren't creating a copy of the bitmap, instead, you're just pointing two different variables at the same underlying object.  So, when you dispose as `mainpic`, that also means that `safecopy` can't be used until it's pointed at a non-disposed object.  In general, you should avoid calling `Dispose` directly, you should prefer to call it implicitly via `Using` blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously think that this is doing something that it is not:

```
safecopy = mainpic
```

All that does is set `safecopy` to refer to the same `Bitmap` object as `mainpic`. There is no copy. The next line disposes that `Bitmap` object so of course you can't then use it. Get rid of the second variable. Just create the object, save it and then dispose it:

```
Using pic As New Bitmap(ofdUploadPhotoMain.FileName)
    pic.Save(IO.Path.Combine(path, "MainPic", fullname + ".png"), Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End Using
```

EDIT:

I just tested this code code and got a generic GDI+ error:

```
Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim fullName = String.Concat("LastName", "FirstName", "MiddleName")
        Dim folderPath = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,
                                      "RMS\Photos\MainPic",
                                      fullName & ".png")
        Dim picture = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName)

        picture.Save(filePath)
        PictureBox1.Image = picture
    End If
End Using
```

In that case, the folder specified in the path did not exist. I changed it to this:

```
Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim fullName = String.Concat("LastName", "FirstName", "MiddleName")
        Dim folderPath = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,
                                      "RMS\Photos\MainPic")

        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)

        Dim filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fullName & ".png")
        Dim picture = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName)

        picture.Save(filePath)
        PictureBox1.Image = picture
    End If
End Using
```

and the image was saved and displayed as expected. The issue is probably the same for you. Notice how I created the path. You should do the same.

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

I get this error on this line

pic.Save(IO.Path.Combine(path, "MainPic", fullname + ".png"), Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

Comment: I have edited my answer to hopefully address your issue.

Comment: Yes, the specified folder doesn't exist. I got it now, thanks to you. I fixed it by creating the directory first. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, that rather uninformative "generic GDI+ error" message occurs under a variety of circumstances. It was luck that I realised that it occurred when the folder didn't exist.